# PayPal Sandbox - Subscribe Using Debit Or Credit Card Not functional

Tags: paypal, credit-card, payment-processing

We have integrated the Sandbox PayPal to our development website in order to check with creation of subscription and the payment process. During the check out process when we proceed with the PayPal check out in Sandbox environment the sign up and the payment then the process is going on well smoothly.

I am able to complete the payment and create a subscription whereas if I select "Subscribe using a debit or credit card" during PayPal Checkout, then an error message is getting displayed after sometime as "We are sorry. Things don't appear to be working at the moment". Every time when I try to subscribe using this "Credit or Debit Card" option in sandbox environment of PayPal, we are getting that error. Can you please suggest on how can I test the creation of subscription by clicking on "Subscribe using Credit or Debit Card"?

Comment: Can some one please let me know why this issue is getting occurred? Is there anything needs to be changed in the PayPal sandox environment?

Comment: Try recreating the button and use the same name for "Item Name" in the button.